# How to export metadata of the material data?

Tags: rendering

So I've been using a procedural planet generator for my game, and I've been trying to achieve exporting material attributes and values as json metadata each time I render a planet.

[image: Shader I'm using]

So I'd like to export all attributes (Seed, Noise Detail, Noise Scale ... Light Brightness) with their values as a individual json file after every render.
Seed: "2384523"
Noise_Detail: "0.047"
.
.
.

Comment: Should be easy with python. Do you have any Python skills?

Comment: So little that they can't help with this one